# $DISPLAY env var gets cleared at random times

Tags: bash, xorg, display, xmonad, tmux

Stock Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. I seem to regularly experience the $DISPLAY environment variable getting cleared for some reason I don't understand.

Basically everything will work just fine until it's cleared and then a vast variety of my command-line tools will stop working because they rely on a $DISPLAY being defined. For example, I can no longer use `xsel -b -i`.

This often happens a few hours into a fresh reboot of the machine. Setting $DISPLAY back to :0 works for some applications, others (such as tmux) not so much.

Note that I'm using both `tmux`, `xmonad` and `gvim` so I'm not sure if this makes any difference.

How do I debug this? This has been bugging me for years.

Comment: The typical issue is starting `tmux` on boot, from crontab, through ssh, or otherwise with `DISPLAY` unset. Whenever you attach `tmux` and/or create a new window, `DISPLAY` will be unset in that window. Meanwhile, it will still be set in all xterms you have started in the session but not attached tmux in. The next time it happens, check if you're using `tmux` in that terminal, and whether it still works fine from a non-tmux terminal.